# Pardot: What is the best way of adding prospects to 2 different lists linked to 2 buttons in an email?

Tags: pardot

My use case is to create an email for prospects to sign in for 2 different events. They have to choose which one they want to go to.

> I added 2 buttons and for each a different link.
> Then I added it in engagement studio with a custom link redirect to 2 lists.

Is this the best option or is there a better and easier one?

Thanks in advance.